# FastAPI + psycopg2: Unable to resolve hostname when trying to connect from within the FastAPI app

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I am trying to connect to local postgres instance that is running on docker. I am able to connect to it using simple python script but when I try to connect from within the FastAPI application, it is unable to translate the hostname and throws the following error

> psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "('localhost'" to address: Name or service not known
> could not translate host name ")" to address: Name or service not known

The code is as follows:

```
import psycopg2
class PgConnector:
def __init__(self, host, user, password, database, port):
    self.user = user,
    self.port = port,
    self.host = host,
    self.password = password,
    self.database = database,
    self.client = None

def get_client(self):
    if not self.client:
        self.client = psycopg2.connect(
            host=self.host,
            user=self.user,
            password=self.password,
            database=self.database,
            port=self.port
        )

    return self.client


pg_connector = PgConnector(host='localhost', user='postgres', port='5432',
                           password='postgres', database='postgres')
```

Comment: After an hour of debugging, it turns out to be a dumb mistake from my end. I had commas at the end of each line of __init__ function which was making the psycopg2 to treat the parameters as tuple causing all the issues.